# ipadOS 17.4: AVCaptureMetadataOutput delegate not called (qrscanner)

Tags: ios, ipad, avfoundation, qr-code

I'm encountering an issue with the QR code scanner on my iPad 7th Gen running ipadOS 17.4. While the scanner seems to be functioning normally on the latest iPad 10th Gen (also on ipadOS 17.4), it's not working at all for ipad 7th gen (ipadOS 17.4) on my device.

It's possible that this problem affects other iPad models but for now I've tested just these two models.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues with the QR code scanner? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or a potential fix would be greatly appreciated.

List of tried device:

- ipad 6Gen: `KO`
- ipad 7Gen: `KO`
- iPad 10Gen: `OK`
- iPhone 15: `OK`
- iPad 8th gen  `OK`
- iPad Air 4th gen `OK`
- iPad Pro 12" 4th Gen `OK`
- iPhone 15 Pro `OK`

#### Minor update

I tried to download AVCam project from official documentation of Apple and I confirm that is not working even in their swift project. But the face recognition is working

### MetadataOutput

```
captureObject = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc]init];
objectQueue =       dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", NULL);//dispatch_queue_create("newQueue", NULL);
[captureObject setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:objectQueue];
```

I tried to use main_queue where creating the dispatch_queue but not
delegating:

```
objectQueue =       dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", NULL);//dispatch_queue_create("newQueue", dispatch_get_main_queue());
```

The problem is that is not delegating nor triggering the method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray<__kindof AVMetadataObject *> *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    
    if (metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count > 0) {
        
        NSLog(@"%@", [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0]);
         
        }
    }
}
```

## WORKAROUND

There is no current solution up to now but i used a workaround using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.

Then use the following output:

```
self.videoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[self.videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
if ([_captureSession canAddOutput:self.videoDataOutput]) {
    [_captureSession addOutput:self.videoDataOutput];
}
```

Then using delegate method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    if (imageBuffer == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:imageBuffer];
    [self detectQRCode:ciImage];
}

-(void)detectQRCode:(CIImage *)image {
    NSDictionary* options;
    CIContext* context = [CIContext context];
    options = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
    CIDetector* qrDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode
                                                context:context
                                                options:options];
//    if ([[image properties] valueForKey:(NSString*) kCGImagePropertyOrientation] == nil) {
//        options = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation : @1};
//    } else {
//        options = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation : [[image properties] valueForKey:(NSString*) kCGImagePropertyOrientation]};
//    }
    
    NSArray * features = [qrDetector featuresInImage:image options:options];
    
    if (features == nil || [features count] == 0) {
        return;
    }
    CIQRCodeFeature *metadataObj = [features firstObject];
    NSString *qrString = [NSString  stringWithString:metadataObj.messageString];
    NSLog(@"feature: %@",qrString);
}
```

## UPDATE

`iOS 17.4.1` fixes the AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate.

Comment: I've encountered this as well, it's very frustrating. I don't know of a workaround yet.

Comment: ipad 6th gen is not working as well

Comment: We're having this problem as well, and it seems to affect scanning on any device that can handle iPadOS 17.4. Scanning works on those devices on 17.3. We are using AVCaptureSession, and thus far the difference between working/not working is that in 17.4, it's never identifying a metadataObject when pointed at a barcode. Why, I have no idea yet.

Comment: reopen if interested. Added some code and more information

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple. I think this was an unintended consequence of something they patched in 17.4. 

https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/13680097

Comment: Seeing the same thing with an iPad 6th gen and iPadOS 17.4 :/

Comment: Not working on iPad 6th gen and iPad 7th gen with iOS 17.4. iPad 8th gen with iOS 17.4 works fine.

Comment: I can confirm scanning working on iPad 8th gen iPad Air 4th gen, iPad Pro 12" 4th Gen,  and iPhone 15 Pro.

Comment: There is a statement regarding this issue from Apple support: https://support.apple.com/en-lamr/118614
It affects iPad 6th & 7th Gen, iPad Pro 12.9-inch (2nd Gen), iPad Pro 10.5-inch

Comment: Thanks to @gtRfnkN 's link. The webpage of it is updated. Now, it said upgrading to iOS 17.4.1 fixes the QR code scanning issue. I confirm that on my iPad 6.

Unfortunately, it seems 17.4.1 fixes only QR code scanning. Bar codes, like Code 39, are not fixed

Comment: I write a post about bar code scanning on Apple Community:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255540933?sortBy=best
Hope Apple fix it soon.